# Animating a Visual State change in Win8 Metro Style App

Tags: expression-blend, windows-runtime, transition, visualstatemanager, winrt-xaml

Working with WPF using Blend 4, you could add animations to visual state changes in the Visual state manager by selecting from a drop down list of effects- It was easy and worked really well.

However, using Blend for Visual Studio 11 Beta for creating Metro Style app, when I click on add transition animation to visual state change in VSM, it goes directly to the story board recording mode. Does anyone know how to animate visual state changes?? (eg: I want the color change of a button on click to fade in). Or hoe do I create those same animations via storyboard??

All responses appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Blend expert, but if you record any Storyboard in Blend - you can then go to XAML view and move your Storyboard to the button's ViewState element (assuming you have extracted the control's template.